# How to point Flask static to Amazon S3 URLs?

Tags: heroku, flask, static-files

I have a Flask app hosted on Heroku but want the static files to be served from Amazon S3.

In my templates I use url_for() for all references to static files. In the initialization of the Flask app I then want to put

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com")
```

to make sure instead of mysite.com/static/, http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/ is used. However I get this error:

```
ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash
```

If I change it to a value with a leading slash it works, but I want the static URL to point to S3, an external domain so it needs to start with http://.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use S3 for static files with Flask and Heroku?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using any of the `static_*` options to the `Flask` object, it is assuming that it'll be responsible for serving those files. A `static` route is configured that serves both as the view to serve the static files and as the `url_for()` target to generate the URLs.

So, with Flask alone, you'd have to replace all `url_for('static', ...)` calls with hardcoded URLs to your CDN instead.

Instead, you should switch to using [Flask-CDN](https://flask-cdn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), a handy Flask add-on to handle seamless switching between static files hosted by Flask and by a CDN:

```
from flask_cdn import CDN

app = Flask(__name__)
cdn = CDN(app)
```

and set the `CDN_DOMAIN` configuration option to `http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` when deploying to production.

In debug mode, `url_for()` will then generate the old `/static/..` urls for Flask to handle, in production mode, `url_for()` prefixes those urls with the `CDN_DOMAIN` value. If the latter is left to the default `None` setting, no such URL alterations take place, making it possible to run Flask locally with `debug` switched off as needed.

Note that the behaviour of `url_for()` is only altered *for Jinja templates*; if you need to generate static URLs in your views, you'll have to swap `flask.url_for()` out for [`flask_cdn.url_for()`](https://flask-cdn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask_cdn.url_for).

Comment: Awesome, this answer worked. Thanks for the elaborate explanation too. I ended up using Flask S3 package (https://flask-s3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) though, as it also can take care of uploading the files to amazon S3 itself with some lines of python. Thanks again!

Comment: @Javaaaa: sure; Flask-S3 uses the exact same pattern as Flask-CDN: replace `url_for()` for templates to generate the CDN URL. But I can imagine that the extra S3 upload functionality comes in very handy for you! :-)