# How to point Flask static to Digitalocean spaces

Tags: python, flask, digital-ocean

I am using url_for in my html pages to access and display static images. I wish to connect flask static to digitalocean spaces instead of AWS S3 as [explained in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279837/how-to-point-flask-static-to-amazon-s3-urls)

I expect that after connecting to digital ocean spaces, the url_for would replace:

original path: static/folder1/image.JPG to

digital ocean spaces: https://{do_space_name}.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/static/folder1/image.JPG

I have tried [Flask-S3](https://flask-s3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) SDK - assuming "Spaces is an S3-compatible object storage service"

```
from flask_s3 import FlaskS3
app.config['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
app.config['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
app.config['FLASKS3_BUCKET_DOMAIN'] = 'sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com'
app.config['FLASKS3_BUCKET_NAME'] = 'do_space_name'
s3 = FlaskS3(app)
```

This generates and replaces the path I expected, but in html it shows error 403 - (Forbidden)

My setting for digitalocean spaces are as below:

> File Listing: Enable

> File Listing (Anyone can list the contents of this Space) CDN (Content

> Delivery Network): disables CORS Configurations: not set

Does it make sense to even attempt something like this? Is there any alternative approach or SDK that can help achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out - this is worth couple of days worth of stupidity...but that's ok.
Answering myself just in case someone stumbles upon:

1: Forbidden error is thrown because my static files in DO spaces was not marked as Public :)

2: I was under (obviously wrong) impression that if I give access key and secret key as config then I need not worry about file level permission

3: But turns out that you can connect to DO spaces even without these, hence what matters is the file level access.

4: For html webpage to access static files, then need to be public.